# Confused about the fallback route in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to update myself to Angular 8 by reading the Angular docs again.

I want to create navigation rules like.

1. by default, enter the index page, redirect to /home, mount to homemodule.
2. there is another /admin, which load children module.
3. if there is no path matched, go to `**` path , it is a pagenotfound component.

I defined a the Routes in `AppRoutingModule`:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    //loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
    loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      routes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only],
    )
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

The `HomeModule` is imported in `AppModule`.

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, PageNotFoundComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, HomeModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The content of HomeRoutingModule is like:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ path: 'home', component: HomePageComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule {}
```

The problem  is when I run the application by `ng serve` command, and open http://localhost:4200.

The url is redirected to http://localhost:4200/home, but the content is **page-not-found works** (it is from `PageNotFoundComponent`).

But if I **remove** `{path: '**',component: PageNotFoundComponent}` in the `AppRoutingModule`, the home page will show as expected.

I am a little confused about the path `''` and `**` in the routing rules.

**Update:** As suggested by @tano. It is resolved by changing the order of `imports` in `AppModule`. `imports: [BrowserModule, HomeModule, AppRoutingModule],` (moved `HomeModule` ahead of `AppRoutingModule`.)

Comment: the order of routes is important, so you should import homemodule first, then approuting module. Since you have eager loading, you can define home route in app-routing module, or use the forroot in app-module imports with empty array and use forchild in approuting..

Comment: Tried it, works.